# Extension for Chrome/Opera GX - Getting url of downloaded file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to rename a file so it will use host as a name. But it doesn't work.

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
    let host = new URL(item.url).hostname.replace(/^www\./, '');
    suggest({filename: host});
});
```

I was looking for some informations on the [chrome developer site](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/) but didn't managed to find anything useful

Comment: As the documentation says "filename is ignored if there are any onDeterminingFilename listeners", so you can't use this listener. Apparently you should specify the filename in chrome.downloads.download.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - 1) Which Chrome version are you using? 2) What is the expected behavior, and what is the actual behavior? 3) Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.